# AWS Lambda - CloudWatch event with constant input - How to get the passed params in Dart?

Tags: dart, aws-lambda

I wtote a very simple AWS lambda function that is triggered by a cloudwatch event with a JSON constant input.

Unfortunately, I cant find a way to retrieve that constant JSON sent by the system in the event object that is passed to my function.

My code is the following:

```
void main() async {
  /// This demo's handling an API Gateway request.
  final Handler<AwsCloudwatchEvent> funcname = (context, event) async {
    print("event.toString():${event.toString()}");
    print("event.toJson():${event.toJson()}");
    print("event.detail:${event.detail}");
    print("event.detailType:${event.detailType}");
    print("event.id:${event.id}");
    print("event.region:${event.region}");
    print("event.resources:${event.resources}");
    print("event.source:${event.source}");
    print("event.time:${event.time}");
    return InvocationResult(
        context.requestId, "0");
  };

  Runtime()
    ..registerHandler<AwsCloudwatchEvent>("funcname", funcname)
    ..invoke();
}
```

Upon invocation, all my prints display *null* besides event.toJson() that displays a classic cloudwatch event structure (but with all fields having a null value). No trace of my constant JSON input...

Output:

```
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.toString():Instance of 'AwsCloudwatchEvent'
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.toJson():{resources: null, region: null, id: null, source: null, account: null, detail-type: null, detail: null, time: null}
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.detail:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.detailType:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.id:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.region:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.resources:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.source:null
2021-02-27T20:55:09.484+01:00   event.time:null
```

Any idea how I could retrieve the passed params in Dart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found it! Just in case someone also has this issue, I'll explain here.

It's not exactly documented, but in order to catch an event with a constant input, we need to use custom events.

Self explanatory code:

```
class MyTriggerEvent extends Event{
  factory MyTriggerEvent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      MyTriggerEvent(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> json_ = Map();

  MyTriggerEvent(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    json_ = json;
  }

  String toJson(){
    return json_.toString();
  }
}
```

and in the lambda function, register the custom event and link it to the handler like this:

```
  Runtime()
    ..registerEvent<MyTriggerEvent>((Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyTriggerEvent.fromJson(json))
    ..registerHandler<MyTriggerEvent>("funcname", funcname)
    ..invoke();
```